# Проблема с гаджетами

Tags: гаджет, xml, html

Здравствуйте! Создал гаджет, сделал архив через WinRar, запустил вылезло окошко с вопросом установить или нет ,нажал установить, но ничего не произошло... В чем дело?

gad.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Бум</title>
<style>
body {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
color: white;
}
div {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p align="center">Привет</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

gad.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gadget>
        <name>Gadget</name>
            <version>1.0</version>
        <author name="Name">
            <info url="site.ru" />
        </author>
    <copyright>Name 2011</copyright>
    <hosts>
        <host name="sidebar">
            <base type="html" apiVersion="1.0.0" src="gad.html"/>
            <permissions>full</permissions>
            <platform minPlatformVersion="1.0"/>
        </host>
    </hosts>
</gadget>
```

Я уже три дня мучаюсь, не могу понять в чем дело... Хотя свой старый гаджет, я собирал заново под другим именем, и он работает, хотя отличается от этого содержимым html и именем в xml-manifest.

Comment: Так берите старый и пошагово переделывайте в новый. ) Сходу ошибку не вижу, но так вы ее точно выловите.

Comment: Вот именно, что я и делал так... Щас попробовал скопировать со старого гаджета содержимое в новый файл и сохранить в другом месте под другим именем, туда перенес xml и все остальные ресурсы. Попробовал собрать и... не работает. Наверно, дело в самом компе, при создании файлов. Файлы старого гаджета были созданы где-то месяц назад. На другом компе гаджет тоже не запускается... Что может быть?

Comment: Виджет, что ли? %)

Comment: Да, гаджет - это десктоп-виджет (http://widgetok.ru/2009/01/what-is-widgets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не поверите, оказывается ошибка была в том, что файл-xml должен именоваться gadget.xml и никак иначе... Я более недели перекраивал код, пока не заметил эту особенность во всех гаджетах!